# What's the correct word to categorize/refer to the Top 1% in a distribution?

Tags: vocabulary, statistics

I've a chart where I'm graphing how much the top 1% of political contributors (the 99th percentile) donate, vs the rest. You can see the graph [here](https://public.tableau.com/profile/wilfredo.contreras/1_Default#!/vizhome/PoliticalContributionsinBC/1_Default), by clicking on "View by" in the top-right corner, and selecting "Percentile." If done correctly, you should get [this view](https://public.tableau.com/profile/wilfredo.contreras#!/vizhome/shared/SF2P4X74H).

Technically, "Percentile" is not the right word (and it's the term I'm asking about in this question---how to replace it), since what is known colloquially as "The 1%" is actually the 99th percentile; hence, I'm not sure how to navigate colloquial understanding vs. the correct understanding.

So, what's the correct term for that "View by" entry?

Comment: Perhaps better answered by users of [math.se]. Try asking there.

Comment: What's wrong with *the top 1%*?

Comment: Presumably if we were talking about the top 10% we would say "the top *decile*", or the top 25% - "the top *quartile*". So, for the top 1% I presume it is *the top *centile*". But it is not a term I have seen much used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Percentile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile)  (Wikipedia)

> A percentile (or a centile) is a measure used in statistics indicating
>   the value below which a given percentage of observations in a group of
>   observations fall. For example, the 20th percentile is the value (or
>   score) below which 20% of the observations may be found.

As Gary notes in a comment, there's also *the top 1 percent*.

Comment: I ended up keeping "Percentile" for the View, and adding "Top 1%" and "Bottom 99%" to the legend.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably if we were talking about the top 10% we would say "the top *decile*", or the top 25% - "the top *quartile*".

So, for the top 1% it is the ***the top *centile***". But that term is less common than *percentile*.

**Indeed the ODO defines *centile* as "another word for *percentile*"**